# How does one programmatically change a constraint on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

When creating a cell in:

```
func tableView ( tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath ) -> UITableViewCell
```

It turns out `cell.constraints.count` equals 0, even though the xib containing the cell layout is packed with them. Implementing the following two functions - which I imagined might be called at opportune moments - produces a similarly disappointing result:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

If I can't *access* the constrains, how can I ever *change* them?

What am I doing wrong here, please? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried subclassing `UITableViewCell` and accessing your constraints in the subclass?

Comment: you can create outlets in your UITableVIewCell, but if you need to get constraints in your UITableViewController, you can access them through cell.contentView.constarints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `IBOutlet` for you `constraint` in your  `UITableViewCell` class then do the changes in `cellforrowatindexpath` method.

ex: in `cellforrowatindexpath`

```
cell.texlabel.topspace.constant = 100;
```

Comment: Thanks @AnuradhS, I like your solution very much.

Comment: if i'm changing the top space what about the cell height ? is it change dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
cell.contentView.constraints
```

It works for me!